# Error after enabling flat Catalog

Tags: indexing, index, flat-catalog

I am getting Fatal error:

```
Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat::loadAllAttributes() in \app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Category.php on line 301 error.
```

When I turn on Flat Catalog and index I get the error. The site has been upgraded from 1.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Method exists at least in EE 1.12 not. So I think your `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category` class is not from actual version.